# how can i use single checkbox for two values?

Tags: javascript

I have one checkbox initially set to `false` if any user checked it, it must be set to `true`

this what i have tried.

```
<div class="control-group">
   <div class="controls">
    <label class="lbl">Force SSL</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="force_ssl" id="force_ssl" /> 
   </div>
</div>
```

when i have dumped it getting `on` instead `1`. in case keep this value in hidden field getting wrong data `0, on`. can anyone help me out what shall i have to change in it ? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the value "true" or "1"?

Comment: The for attribute of your label needs to *match* the id of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `value` to your checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="force_ssl" id="force_ssl" value="1" />
```

Comment: if I keep value = 1 it will be always be true whenever form get submitted, I want to set it false by default in case any user checked it must be set to true.

Comment: @waseem — No, you won't, that isn't how checkboxes work. Checking it doesn't change the value, it determines if it will be submitted or not.

Comment: @waseem Note that the input will not get submitted if the box is not checked.  Checking for existence is required at the server (in which case the "value" is immaterial)